# Grails inject Service into Controller dependant on environment

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection

I have a situation in a Controller where I'm surrounding pieces of code in `if(Environment.Current == Environment.PRODUCTION)` blocks because the block of code is calling `methodA` in `restService` that makes a REST call to a URL that is only available when the app is deployed onto a specific production server. However doing so means that area of code is unreachable when running tests, which makes me a bit uncomfortable.

In the Development environment I'm not concerned with making the call to `methodA` as I'm stubbing out what the `methodA` would return and passing it on to the next Controller, so changing the if statement to `if(Environment.Current != Environment.DEVELOPMENT)` allows me to test the code better and not have to make calls to places I can't reach during dev.

Ideally though I would like to try and inject a Service into a Controller dependent on the grails environment; so I could have two Services like this:

```
class RestService {
  def methodA() {
    // go do a REST call
  }
}
```

and

```
class FakeRestService() {
  def methodA() {
    // return some stubbed response
  }
}
```

and in my Controller `restService` would be an instance of `FakeRestService` in DEVELOPMENT and TEST environments, and an instance of `RestService` in PRODUCTION

```
class SearchController {
  def restService

  def index() {
    restService.methodA()
  }
```

I'm a bit stumped on how I could achieve this in a 'Grailsy'/Spring way. I've been looking into creating some sort of Service Factory which would return an instance of either `RestService` or `FakeRestService` dependent on the environment, but it would be nice if I could define what Service to inject into `restService` in config or something similar.

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an alias for the bean name in `resources.groovy` when environment is TEST.

```
import grails.util.Environment

beans = {
    if ( Environment.current == Environment.TEST ) {
        springConfig.addAlias 'restService', 'fakeRestService'
    }
}
```

[`RuntimeSpringConfiguration`](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/spring/RuntimeSpringConfiguration.html#addAlias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is available in resources.groovy by `getSpringConfig()`.

Comment: Great elegant solution to the problem. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more Grails-y version of dmahapatro's answer:

```
import grails.util.Environment

beans = {
    Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment {
        environments {
            development {
                springConfig.addAlias 'restService', 'fakeRestService'
            }
        }
    }
}
```